# Replace L, in SQL results in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyodbc

I'm running pyodbc connected to my db and when i run a simply query I get a load of results back such as

```
(7L, )(12L,) etc.
```

How do I replace the the 'L, ' with '' so I can pass the ids into another query

Thanks

Here's my code

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=...;UID=...;PWD=...', ansi=True)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
rows = cursor.execute("select id from orders")
for row in rows:
    test = cursor.execute("select name from customer where order_id = %(id)s" %{'id':row})
    print test
```

Comment: You don't need or want to. These are tuples consisting of single long integers each. If you have a problem with the format, you should show how you are retrieving them and where you are having problems passing them into the other query.

Comment: Added what I am trying to do, if i try and pass in 7L i get Syntax error at or near "L" at character 45\n

Comment: This typically means that there is a Syntax error **somewhere around** L - could also be a missing or surplus comma, for example. Are you really sure the L is the reason for the error? Consider posting your full query here...

Comment: That essentially is my query, im just testing it trying to get it to work, i put a limit on the first but that is it

Answer (score 0):

Use [parameters](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted#Parameters):

```
...
test = cursor.execute("select name from customer where order_id = ?", row.id)
...
```

The `L` after the number indicates that the value is a [long](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.LongType) type.